# NestJS Microservice doesn't instantiate when importing DatabaseModule to App.Module

Tags: database, mongoose, service, nestjs, typeorm

I am creating a Microservice with NestJS with a DatabaseModule that connects to two databases. I import the DatabaseModule into the AppModule's imports array.

When I import the DatabaseModule to AppModule the Microservice stops instantiating. When I don't include the import of the DatabaseModule the Microservice instantiates and prints 'Microservice is listening!' to the terminal.

What about the DatabaseModule is preventing the Microservice from instantiating with `createMicroservice()` method? Any suggestions?

All help is much appreciated!

main.ts

```
import { Transport, MicroserviceOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
      transport: Transport.TCP,
    }
  );
  await app.listen(async () => console.log('Microservice is listening!'));
}

bootstrap();
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import 'dotenv/config';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

database.module.ts

```
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose'; 

import { Token } from '../token/token.entity';
import { TokenService } from '../token/token.service';
import { TokenModule } from '../token/token.module';
import { NotificationModule } from '../notification/notification.module';
import { NotificationService } from '../notification/notification.service';

const dbUsername = process.env.DB_USER;
const dbPassword = process.env.DB_PASS;
const dbName = process.env.DB_NAME;
const dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST;

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [NotificationModule],
            useFactory: () => ({
                uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/notifications-app'
            }),
            inject: [NotificationService]
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [TokenModule],
            useFactory: () => ({
                type: 'mysql',
                host: dbHost,
                port: 3306,
                username: dbUsername,
                password: dbPassword,
                database: dbName,
                entities: [Token],
                synchronize: true,
                insecureAuth: true,
                logging: true,
            }),
            inject: [TokenService]
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Token]),
    ],
})
export class DatabaseModule { }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, or does the application just hang?

Comment: The application loads but the Microservice doesn't connect with the client.